# SQL select, from, where, how

Tags: php, sql

I have this little issue with sql that doesn't function. I have a query which grows based on specific critera. Here it is

```
$SELECT = ' SELECT * ';
$FROM  = '  FROM a ';
$WHERE = '  WHERE TRUE ';
$how = ' GROUP By a_id ';

$result = mysqli_query($link, $SELECT . $FROM . $WHERE . $how );
```

This works but the second stage doesn't

```
$FROM .= "  INNER JOIN b ON b_aid = a_id";
$WHERE .= " AND b_id = $id";
```

Specifically, the additional     $WHERE . causes an undefined variable. If it is removed, I can see within the array the line I am after.

The normal query $result = mysqli_query($link, $SQL) works ok for the above;
Thanks

Comment: The code in between would be relevant. -- Where does `$id` come from?

Comment: For query questions, the best way to get an answer is to: 1) add the table definition.  2) add sample data.  3) add sample output.  4) print the value of the built query.  Just before you run it, do a print of the completed query and add it here.

Comment: My guess is that you will need to include table names/alias on duplicate column names.  It is hard to tell if this is the case because you are only posting pseudo-code.  What I mean is, you will need to reference columns in `$FROM`, `$how`, and `$WHERE` (possibly more) including their table name/alias like: ` `ON b.b_id=a.a_id` and `a.a_id` and `b.b_id=$id` _respectively_.  As it is currently posted, your question is unclear and may be closed.  Please follow Nic3500's advice ASAP.

Comment: as an added tip: if your question involves an error message `include the error message`

Comment: There is zero pseudo-code in the above.

Comment: There is absolutely zero pseudo-code in the above-->  $SELECT "." $FROM "." $WHERE "." $HOW . They join to make the SQL request and the data is listed right above this. $link is just a database link that I use many times over. $id is a variable dependent on a selection like integers "1" or "10". Table 1 name is "a" and Table 2 name is "b".  The questions legit